# 連続した全角空白を１つの全角空白で置き換えたい

Tags: python, 正規表現

```
u"名前１　　　名前２　　　名前３　名前４　　　"
```

上記の文字列において、連続して２つ以上ある全角空白を１つの全角空白で置き換えたいです。

Answer (score 1):

質問内容をそのままコードに書き下しました (Python3)

```
import re

text = u"名前１　　　名前２　　　名前３　名前４　　　"
print(re.sub('[\u3000]{2,}', '\u3000', text))
```

追記： Python2.7用に書き直すとこうなります

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

text = u"名前１　　　名前２　　　名前３　名前４　　　"
print(re.sub(u'[\u3000]{2,}', u'\u3000', text))
```

Comment: 変数`text`が全角スペースを含まないのは意図的な物ですか？ また、正規表現において全角スペースを`[]`で囲む必要はあるのでしょうか

Comment: `text`は意図的なものです(質問内で提示された文字列をあえてそのままコピペしました)。`[]`で囲むのは好みの問題だと思います。ここでは「全角スペース1文字だけが後続する`{2,}`の対象になっている」ことを強調させる意味で使っています。

Comment: なるほど。このままだと「何もする必要が無い」が答えになってしまうので、質問を編集して文字列に全角スペースを入れてしまいました。

Comment: 量指定子が対象とする部分を強調するためであれば、`[]`ではなく`(?:)`または`()`を使った方が良いと思います